# How to connect to a SQL Server database from a separate Oracle SQL Developer's Server?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, oracle-sqldeveloper, jtds

I cannot connect to a SQL Server database through SQL Developer (Oracle).
It gives the following error: "Status : Failed Test failed: I/O Error: Unknown packet type 0x48"

I was able to connect with SQL Server Management Studio, but I need to connect through SQL Developer.

I tried using JDBC jtds 1.2, and 1.3.1 and both didn't work.

I was able to connect with SQL Server Management Studio, but I need to connect through SQL Developer. I use JDBC jtds 1.2, but I've already tested it with 1.3.1 and it wasn't either.

[image]

Comment: First check your port.  SQL Server default port is 1433, your config img uses 8080.

Comment: The jTDS driver is extremely outdated. You should use the Microsoft JDBC driver

Comment: @squillman When I try connect with default port (1433) apresent this error: "Status : Failure -Test failed: Cannot connect to Microsoft SQL Server on srv-sgi"

Comment: You should compare to how you're connecting in ssms. It's hard to say but i'm guessing you're using wrong port (even 1433 might not be correct)